# Slicing a graph

Tags: python, indexing, graph, slice

I have created a graph in python but I now need to take a section of the graph and expand this by using a small range of the original data, but I don't know how to find the row number of the results that form the range or how I can create a graph using just these results form the file. This is the code I have for the graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#variable for data to plot
spec_to_plot = "SN2012fr_20121129.42_wifes_BR.dat"

#tells python where to look for the file
spec_directory = '/home/fh1u16/Documents/spectra/' 
data = np.loadtxt(spec_directory + spec_to_plot, dtype=np.float)

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("Wavelength")
plt.ylabel("Flux")
plt.title(spec_to_plot)
plt.show()
```

edit: data is between 3.5e+3 and 9.9e+3 in the first column, I need to use just the data between 5.5e+3 and 6e+3 to plot another graph, but this only applies to the first column. Hope this makes a bit more sense?
Python version 2.7

Comment: This is quite unclear, but I bet clicking the magnifier icon in your graph window and selecting the portion you want will do just what you are after.

Comment: What is unclear? How do I make it clearer?

Comment: We can't know what slice is relevant to you if you don't explain your problem...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could do it this way:

```
my_slice = slice(np.argwhere(x>5.5e3)[0], np.argwhere(x>6e3)[0])
x = data[my_slice,0]
y = data[my_slice,1]
```

`np.argwhere(x>5.5e3)[0]` is the index of the first occurrence of `x>5.5e3` and like wise for the end of the slice. (assuming your data is sorted)

A more general way working even if your data is not sorted:

```
mask = (x>5.5e3) & (x<6e3)
x = data[mask, 0]
y = data[mask, 1]
```

Comment: Just tried this and error "x and y must have same first dimension" appeared?

Comment: you need to apply the same slicing to `y`, see my edit.

Comment: don't put code like that in comments, it's not readable, prefer editing your post... Don't use `and` but `&`, they have different meaning.

Comment: Actually I'm surprised you didn't get an error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` using `and` instead of `&`... which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

solved by using

```
plt.axis([5500, 6000, 0, 8e-15])
```

thanks for help.